# How to "grep" list of columns not ending in "x"

Tags: regex, r

I need to create a list of variables in R to use in another procedure. I want to exclude all the variables that end in "usd". I am using `grep` but couldn't do it with:

```
h <- grep(!'*.usd$', colnames(mk2), value=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't just stick `!` in front of a regular expression to invert it i'm afraid. But if you check out the `?grep` help page, you'll see that `grep` has an `invert=` parameter. Try

```
mk2 <- data.frame("ausd"=1,"busd"=2,"ceur"=3,"deru"=4,"eusd"=5)
h <- grep('usd$', colnames(mk2), value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
# [1] "ceur" "deru"
```

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use `grepl` (using @MrFlick) example data

```
colnames(mk2)[!grepl('usd$', colnames(mk2))]
## [1] "ceur" "deru"
```